# Not Able To Parse Web Response Content

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve JSON from a URL and read it into my application.  I am having an issue when reading the WebResponse.  When the response is read, it comes back as only Symbols and is not properly formatted json.

**How do I get a properly formatted JSON after streaming my WebResponse?**

My Javascript is as follows:

```
 function getJsonWM() {
            //var stringedData = JSON.stringify(ajaxData);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Default/GetQuestionByHighestScore',
                //data: JSON.stringify("{}"),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var label = $("#lblResults");
                    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
                    label.text(json);

                    //if (data.d.Pin == undefined) {
                    //    alert("Error: " + data.d.ErrorMessage);
                    //} else {
                    //    alert("Please record the following PIN: \r\n \r\n" + data.d.Pin);
                    //}
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //alert("Error: " + data.d.ErrorMessage);
                }
            });
        }

$(function() {
    //$("#btnSubmit").click(getJson);
    $("#btnSubmit").click(getJsonWM);
});
```

My controller is as follows:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
    private const string questionUrl = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow";


    public string GetQuestionByHighestScore()
            {
                List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
                var json = GetJson(questionUrl);
                var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json);

                return list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            }

    public string GetJson(string url)
            {
                var myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                var myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
                string strResponse = String.Empty;
                var encoding = Encoding.Default;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
                {
                    //JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                return strResponse;
            }
}
```

My strResponse object is as follows:

```
"‹\b\0\0\0\0\0\0µ\\\vÛ6¶þ+„\bÚ{G£%Q)‚ÜI“4\t6»iÓtw/”HÙšÑÃ•ä™8Eÿû=‡”ly,y$·iÐ%òóññ¼éßi#ózñô[4|‰wÑe!›ÅÅ\"ßdMÚ¬*ÉEZ,ÿw±(ï\vY-žþ¶¨äzÓð&-‹ÅSÛv/›ZV×©X<umæYžÝ¾i¶k¹x\nÝ—iÝÈJ\n`ËãX®›ëŠ7ÐÄØÅb]•IšÉë4çKì½jšuýÔ4ÓËºáñíeš/7Õe\\ææÏôêþß—7ëåóú™í°'Ëg60i½Îøöºà9’¼ÝþÄsÙÅ\"K‹Û–!ðSÜÊ;Y%Yy¯øák³²Yßn+EøûÅ\"­¯yQß«!?MxVË‹Å]*ï¯ãrS40i\a&¢:ìÞ\\,ê¸¬`|1¯›k7é]Úl¯…šªM=›:®ãBÏW¯ßd‡¡¶¤R¤Í™­Öô×¬™Zih`®CŸfGSmiLµ·Æns\rØƒÏ[#^ÉøVVFÝÈ¸1Š²1jÙMiðÂH\và\\ÄÒ(|Ô}`‘#®û{ÅòçŽ%Q,IË’ü]u'À’\0KÒ”„¤cIÊ[–¿_ìÁ˜oë_3ø’uY7ËJê\ažó/eaÀÞÔ«4iF‘é[¬‡L'p=Ë\n§\"3\bÆ‘y¹¬øo¸¦þhºŒ\a¡—D‚òÀŠBG¸’{^è‹˜E2òe\v[ñ,²hÒ¸,žTÏ>üð$Âñ\aÞ4+m–“ÜÎÐ\\ï(§ ù!­©@v¼a ·MG`\rÄsÁŠ4fšÃFÜIc\rÝÊ*ï@\bs4 wµ565b¸*ïb“G\0„=*ßjZÒ£E´-Q´DÑ ½niûð[o›•’$u\t(nêq!Ø—¥>sN!m\fXÙÊ¿\\–å2“H\nøh\0'jYŒ¼æÅ««7âê­yµû¯÷ùÅ'35~i^_Õ/£[s½*›RËÊ/ˆºc€}¿ªÒšü$y6aíÌÌIá\0éˆ¹gcÌG0qTXj²caÉ|¶°“g°oŒ0\b²PcÁÐÒÂÈ%@DôwµïbN÷¾Ô½¿ù–´ýû(«6ÑÖ@ÆÓ¬NøŒ˜“YkœÀºjÇ¥\\yãû¨f#oL¤IGDÂñ¤ð…å$qB=Ï±œ€ZüBo–H“U&\vqS®øtíÜNÉìÓNÀ.Â˜‚¶ÏÂœZvh\ràÊòèl¹†4æýŠ7µc9¨7C&I§°ŠÆ=ß* É\fÕ0Gí,61ô­7ÑþB½è^ö0øà"
```

Comment: `GetQuestionByHighestScore` - is this ASP.NET MVC controller action or ASP.NET Web API controller action?

Comment: GetQuestionByHighestScore is the Action.  The controller is DefaultController.  I will edit the post to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the server returns gzip encoded response. So make sure that you have set the [`AutomaticDecompression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression(v=vs.110).aspx) property when making your HTTP request:

```
public string GetJson(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return strResponse;
    }
}
```

Also please get rid of those `application/json` content types. You are making a GET request which doesn't have a body - you are not sending any JSON. Also get rid of the `contentType` switch in your jQuery AJAX request (same reason).

Comment: I have never heard of GZip.  Thanks!

Comment: The server tells you this using the `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header. So the client must comply in order to understand the response. GZIP is a standard encoding used in the HTTP protocol to reduce the bandwidth usage and improve performance of web applications.